# Vagrant + YML for provisioning

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile

Just getting started with vagrant and hoping to get a bit of guidance - I imagine this might be a simple task:

I'm using a yml file to manage the config for my `Vagrantfile` like so:

```
require 'yaml'

# read yaml file
settings = YAML.load_file('SETTINGS.yml')

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  # Define VM Box
  config.vm.box = settings['server']['box']
  config.vm.box_url = settings['server']['box_url']
  config.vm.hostname = settings['server']['name']

  ... etc ...
```

My `SETTINGS.yml` looks like this:

```
server:
  name: denv-libweb
  box: ol7-latest
  box_url: https://yum.oracle.com/boxes/oraclelinux/latest/ol7-latest.box 
  ram: 1024
  cpus: 2
  ports:
    - guest: 80
      host: 8081
```

This all works great, but what I'd like to do is continue using the `SETTINGS.yml` file to manage configurations performed in the provisioning script, `provision.sh`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ settings['provision']['apache'] ]; then
  yum -y install apache
fi
```

Where `settings['provision']['apache']` refers to my `SETTINGS.yml` file:

```
provision:
  apache: true
  mysql_user: dbuser
  mysql_pw: dbpassword
  ... etc ...
```

Am I approaching this the right way? Is there a better way?

How can I use my settings.yml to configure the provisioning script?

Comment: If you want to do YAML-based provisioning, I'd suggest you go with SaltStack or Ansible (both officially supported by Vagrant) rather than roll your own.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll look into both. Question: does something like Ansible only come into play on provisioning? or can I also use Ansible to manage the configuration of my Vagrantfile?

Comment: No, both Ansible and SaltStack are only for provisioning. There are tools that do everything in one configuration file, but they are quite different from Vagrant: Docker, which is not a VM, and Nix/NixOps, which is basically functional package management and currently quite experimental.